# Excel calculate value of cell to left, and cell to right in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, self-reference

I'm currently in cell C3, Trying to grab cell B3, and use it to find the product of it with D3.

Basically, I want C3=(B3*(D3/100)). For multiple rows.

But I want it uniform, to follow an unknown number of rows down, somewhere between 25-150.  So I would rather not have to hardcore and change each row's number from 3, to 4, to 5, for 150 rows.

I'm kind of new to excel, but I've been trying to figure it out, and I've tried working with indirect and address and stuff, but I just can't figure it out.

Thank you in advance, for anyone who can help.

Comment: Click on the cell with the formula and, using the corner of the cell, click and drag it down to row 150 or wherever you are wanting to stop. Conversely you can copy and paste and Excel will do this automagically. You can "Lock" the reference to the row or column so it doesn't change automatically by using a `$` sign in front of the row or column. Say you wanted B3 to stay B3, but D3 to change to D4, D5, etc, then: `=(B$3*(D3/100))`

Comment: See [Is there a way to autofill cells in Excel 2013 with keyboard shortcuts?]

Answer (score 0):

If you copy C3 cell and paste it in C4 cell, excel will automatically do this for you!

Usually the problem is to prevent that from happening. (if you are curious, to do that you have to add a $ where you want the formula not to change, for exemple: if the formula was `C3=(B$3*(D3/100))` instead, when you copy/paste it as i said above, you would end up with `C4=(B3*(D4/100))`)